# Find the $\min_{v\in V}p(v,w) \forall w \in G$, where $p(v,w)$ is the shortest path between $w \to v$

Tags: graph-theory

**Q**: Let $ p(u, v)$ be the shortest path weight from $u$ to $v$: Give an $O(VE)$ algorithm
to find the $\underset{v\in V}{\min}p\left( v,w \right) \forall w \in G$. Note that the algorithm should find $\underset{v\in V}{\min}p\left( v,w \right)$ for all vertices $ w$ and should run in $O(VE)$, where $G$ is a directed graph, $V$ vertices of graph and $E$ edges of a graph.

We can clearly see that this is Bellman–Ford application, so I don't really know what extra we need to add to Bellman–Ford original algorithm to answer this question unless I don't understand the question clearly please?

The answer says that, a modification to Bellman–Ford is as follows:

$$d_t(v) = \min\left(d_{t-1}(v), \min_{u:u \in \text{adj}[v]}(d_{t-1}(u)+w(u,v)\right)$$

**Problem**: I really don't get the modification and what it really adds to Bellman–Ford algorithm below (courtesy to Algorithms by Goodrich et al.). I see both are the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the "modification" just seems to be the regular updating rule in Bellman-Ford. But Bellman-Ford by itself does not give an answer to your question in $O(|V||E|)$ time.

The point is that Bellman-Ford finds the shortest paths starting from a source $v$ to every other vertex $w$, while what you want is to find a shortest path ending in $w$, for each vertex $w$. You could run Bellman-Ford $|V|$ times to find a shortest path between any two vertices and then use this to compute for every vertex $w$ a shortest path ending in $w$, but this would take $O(|V|^2|E|)$ time. However, you can use a trick that gives you the answer in one iteration of Bellman-Ford.

> The trick is to add a new vertex $u$ to the graph, along with a zero cost directed edge $uv$ for every vertex $v \in V$. You can convince yourself that running Bellman-Ford with $u$ as the source gives you a shortest path ending in each vertex. If you examine what the algorithm does in this case, you'll find that it is just the regular Bellman-Ford algorithm in the original graph with the modification that at the start, the potential $D(v)$ is set to $0$ for every vertex $v \in V$.